# Neopixel Painter - Need to change few lines. Not sure where to start

Tags: arduino-uno, neopixel

My name is Maria and I'm learning programing in high school.
I'm working on a birthday present for my mom, want to make a mood light. Using light painter, a neopixel strip, and an arduino.

https://github.com/adafruit/NeoPixel_Painter

I found the part, which reads the bmp line by line a very innovative way to make custom animations.

But some tweaks are needed. (I've tried to make them, believe me, oh I've tried.) So, i was wondering if i can ask someone a favor and teach me how to modify the code (like, comment on parts that been changed.)

Basically, what I want to be changed is, to loop the current bmp until 'next' button is pressed, rather than hold the trigger. Also, I'm not sure if the code try to save power, but it can be disabled since it will run from a power supply.

Here is the part that makes you hold the trigger button (i think)

```
  for(;;) {
    while(!(TIFR1 & _BV(TOV1)));               // Wait for Timer1 overflow
    TIFR1 |= _BV(TOV1);                        // Clear overflow bit

    show();                                    // Display current line
    if(stopFlag) break;                        // Break when done

    if(++block >= nBlocks) {                   // Past last block?
      if(digitalRead(TRIGGER) == HIGH) {       // Trigger released?
        memset(sdBuf, 0, N_LEDS * 3);          // LEDs off on next pass
        stopFlag = true;                       // Stop playback on next pass
        continue;
      }                                        // Else trigger still held
      block = 0;                               // Loop back to start
    }
    card.readBlock(block + firstBlock, sdBuf); // Load next pixel row
  }
```

And the complete code: https://github.com/adafruit/NeoPixel_Painter/blob/master/NeoPixel_Painter.ino

Anyway, Since I'm talking to an experts right now, I have this idea to remote control the code! from  another arduino!

My, probably retarded idea is, to run an IR remote code on a second arduion, than when it receives a signal, send a simulated button press to the first ardu playing the bmp! Is that even possible? Just wondering.

Cheers
Maria

Comment: I can't see anything there that tries to save power. Remote controlling should be easy enough, grab some IR transmitter examples. It should be easy enough to set up a transmitter on one Arduino, and a receiver on another. Experiment with that first, before trying to control lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

```
  for(;;) {
    while(!(TIFR1 & _BV(TOV1)));               // Wait for Timer1 overflow
    TIFR1 |= _BV(TOV1);                        // Clear overflow bit

    show();                                    // Display current line

    if(++block >= nBlocks) {                   // Past last block?
      block = 0;                               // Loop back to start
    }

    if(digitalRead(NEXT_PIN_OR_SOMETHING) == LOW) {       // Next button pressed
      break; // Break out of for-loop
    }


    card.readBlock(block + firstBlock, sdBuf); // Load next pixel row
  }
```